# Writing code to read commands from a file - understanding markup style strings using Python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I would like to write a program to read a psudoocode style text file that reads structured commands in a text file and "understands" the logic written in the file.  Specifically, I would like to convert [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram) syntax, into a UML style definition for certain files (specifically a sequence diagram)

the typical file would look like this:

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response

Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: Another authentication Response
@enduml
```

As per the PlantUML spec, there are many conditions for this file (syntax and language wise) -- but I plan to read this file, and interface through the Standard API of a specific UML tool, to draw the diagram in that particular tool.

I am stuck as to HOW i would apply logic to understand the logic, given instructions could be on multi-line, and some commands could have html injected into the word, as an example,
`Alice -[#0000FF]->Bob : ok`

I have tried some initial attempts, and am happy to post my attempt, however, the question is rather if there are any standard frameworks to break this logic down -- do I just implement many "case" style statements and execute a function for each case?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/plantuml/ Have you seen this?

Comment: Thank you!. I did not look at that. I think it will help to move from UML form back to PlantUML syntax, however, i dont think it will help for the reverse.